# The decimal floating point representation with e

Tags: floating-point, programming-languages

Many programming languages support floating-point values in decimal scientific notation with the syntax -1.23e-22 or 1.23E+22, where the first part is the significand and the second the exponent. These can often be used as literals, or when printing or inputting data.

What is the name of this notation? What is its origin? What languages do and do not support it?

Comment: There is a section in Wikipedia on this representation of scientific notation: [E-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation).

Comment: Note: ["mantissa"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand#Use_of_.22mantissa.22) has a  variant meaning when the exponent is negative. IEEE specs use "significand".  It is  less ambiguous.